# list of (string, some_list) tuples to list of [string, <items from some_list>] lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples of two elements. The first element is a string, the second one is a list. I want to create a list of lists with all the elements of a single tuple. I have tried with the append method, but it returns me an empty list. I also tried list concatenation, but it returns me only the last tuple in the final list.

```
lista = [('una Tantum', ['Frasi latine']), ('Montagna', ['Montagna', 'Geomorfologia']), ('Ande', ['Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia']), ('Ande', ['Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia'])]
for x in lista:
    data = [x[0]]+x[1] # in this way the data variable is populated only with the last element e.g. data = ('Ande', ['Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia'])
    print data
```

I have tried also with:

```
for x in lista:
   x[1].append(x[0])
```

But it returns to me an empty list. Please help me

The desired result is:

```
[['una Tantum', 'Frasi latine'], ['Montagna', 'Montagna', 'Geomorfologia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia']]
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Please put it in your question, in a code block.

Comment: `data` is populated with the last element because you overwrite `data` every loop, so in the end you will have the result of the last loop

Comment: Your second code does not return a plank/blank list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your first approach to a list comprehension, in order to preserve all the expanded sub lists in a new list. Also its more pythonic than python regular loop.

```
>>> [[item]+sub_list for item,sub_list in lista]
[['una Tantum', 'Frasi latine'], ['Montagna', 'Montagna', 'Geomorfologia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', u'Gruppi montuosi del Per\xf9', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, in Python3.5 you do it like this:

```
>>> [[x, *l] for x,l in lista]
[['una Tantum', 'Frasi latine'], ['Montagna', 'Montagna', 'Geomorfologia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', 'Gruppi montuosi del Perù', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia'], ['Ande', 'Ande', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Argentina", 'Gruppi montuosi del Cile', 'Gruppi montuosi del Perù', 'Gruppi montuosi della Bolivia', "Gruppi montuosi dell'Ecuador", 'Gruppi montuosi del Venezuela', 'Gruppi montuosi della Colombia']]
```

Answer (score 0):

map(lambda x: [x[0]] + x[1], [('A', ['Jay', 'Hi']), ('B', ['Jay', 'Hello'])])

Answer (score -2):

As I understand, you want to convert all tuples to lists :
In python v3:

```
list(map(list, l))
```

Or in python v2:

```
map(list, l)
```

*Note* :

- `l` is your list (`lista`)